# Loading several Json files from a folder in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to load a set of json files from a separate director, which *appears* to work when loading them in. jsonlist is loaded in and looks like this:

['recording0.json', 'recording1.json', 'recording2.json', 'recording3.json']

However, when I want to load in the actual data, it tells me there is no json file to load in. I *think* it's to do with the path but I have no idea. There's a very similar question on here, but the answer doesn't seem to wrok for me.

```
for data in jsonlist:
    datafile = INPUT_DIR + data
    with open(datafile, 'r') as json_file:
        json_data = json_file.read()
        stamps_and_coordinates = json.loads(json_data)
```

"No JSON object could be decoded"

EDIT: I'm loading in jsonlist with this:

```
filelist = [f for f in listdir(INPUT_DIR) if isfile(join(INPUT_DIR, f))]
jsonlist = []
 for i in filelist:
     if i.endswith('.json'):
         jsonlist.append(i)
```

Incredibly shortened version example of json content below:

```
[{"Timestamp":"1184134472","DeltaTime":"42147765","PerceptorStamp":"39.6890000000005","X":1182.913,"Y":677.6516},
{"Timestamp":"1184149377","DeltaTime":"42162670","PerceptorStamp":"39.7120000000006","X":1175.157,"Y":679.6996},
{"Timestamp":"1184162553","DeltaTime":"42175846","PerceptorStamp":"39.7120000000006","X":1193.353,"Y":671.6687}]
```

Comment: First check the contents of json_data. In every programming language it opens the file based on the current directory, this may not be the same as the exe/python file directory. So either provide the full path, or make sure you run it from the correct path.

Comment: That's just it, json_data reads the contents of the json file perfectly.

Comment: So your JSON is invalid: verify it via http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @TerraCode post a sample of your Json data

Comment: Used the site RvdK gave me, jsons are valid.

Comment: I feel like such an idiot. The eight json was invalid. Stray comma. Somehow. Thanks for the help!